# selenium doesn't click flash upload in an embed tag

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, embed-tag

I tried to click on it directly and tried switching frame but it doesn't automate it when i manually click on it it works an d open a window popup to upload file 
but using selenium it doesn't:

```
<div>
    <input id="id" name="name" type="file" class="class" size="31" style="display: none; background-color: grey;" width="95" height="31">
    <embed src="some_url" quality="high" width="95" height="31" id="fnameUploader" class="fileUploaderBtn" name="fnameUploader" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</div>
```

Comment: What code do you have at this point? Is it inside an iframe - if yes, show the HTML code including it. Thanks.

Comment: it is not in any iframe just an embed tag while i was google i found out that this can be handle using switch frame but i failed to do so
here is the complete Xpath "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/ul[2]/div"

Comment: OK, Can you show your Complete code Implementation for the same?

Comment: `embedtag=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ysi_fname_addfile_box']/embed")`

`self.driver.switch_to_frame(embedtag)`
`embedtag.click()#this should open a window popup but it doesn't do any thing no popup no exception`
@RupeshShinde ingnore the formatting this is thing is not working

Comment: Instead of Xpath ("//div[@id='ysi_fname_addfile_box']/‌​embed"), Please try to use this Xpath and see what happens.                    embedtag=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //input[@id='id']//embed[@type='application/x-shockwave-flash']")

Comment: i tried that too it click but browser doesn't detect it....